# Notifications via cron (MacOS)

Tags: bash, macos, osascript

I've got a script which disables Internet Sharing function on Macbook, then sends a GUI notification via osascript and an email.

It works perfectly, but i don't get notifications when it run in cron.

```
if [ "$(defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat | grep -i Enabled | sed -e 's/.*0/0/g' | sed 's/.$//')" != 0 ]; then
    defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.nat NAT -dict Enabled -int 0
    osascript -e 'display notification "Internet Sharing disabled" with title "Attention!" sound name "Ping"'
    echo "Attempted to enable Interen Sharing on host $(hostname)" | mail -s "Alert" name@domain.com
fi
```

Comment: I just test your script. It worked for me (defaults, osascript, and mail). Can you log the cron: `/path/to/script/cron-notify.sh > /tmp/cron.log 2>&1` Also make sure the cron-notify.sh script starts with `#!/bin/bash` which cron defaults to sh and the $() is bash specific

Comment: cron.log in my case looks like this:
 - osascript[2375:56477] NSNotificationCenter connection invalid
 - osascript[2375:56477] Connection to notification centerinvalidServerConnectionFailure: 1 invalidated: 0
 - osascript[2375:56477] Connection to notification center invalid. ServerConnectionFailure: 1 invalidated: 0